# How can I prove that $a_{n}$ and $a_{3n+2}$ converge to the same value?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am given that $a_{n}\to L$, how can I prove that $a_{3n+2} \to L$ also? It makes sense since $3n + 2$ is still in $\mathbb{N}$, but I don't know how to say that in proof form.

Comment: Do you know the rigorous definition of limit?

Comment: Work from the definition of limit. What do you know since $a_n\to L$?

Comment: It's the internet, we can type whole words, @BrianDing, and not everybody here knows enough English to know what word you are abbreviating.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n\to L$.  Let $b_n=a_{3n+2}$.  Let $\epsilon>0$.  Find $N$ such that $n>N$ $\Rightarrow$ $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.  Then for that same $N$, $n>N$ implies $|b_n-L|=|a_{3n+2}-L|<\epsilon$ because $3n+2>n>N$.  QED

Answer (score 0):

We actually have a stronger result: If a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to a limit $L$, then every subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ converges to the same limit. $\{a_{3n+2}\}$ is a subsequence, so it converges to $L$.

Let $a_n\rightarrow L$, take $\varepsilon>0$, and let $\{a_{n_k}\}$ be a subsequence. Choose $N$ large enough so that

$n\geq N\Longrightarrow|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$

Then, since $n_k\geq k$,

$k\geq N\Longrightarrow n_k\geq N\Longrightarrow|a_{n_k}-L|<\varepsilon$

Comment: Well, yeah, but OP is asking *why* this is true.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is looking for, I think they want essentially the proof of the statement you are reducing it to.

Comment: Good point; just edited it